# List files from certain folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to find the `.seq` files from `src` folder and its sub-directories. I'm trying with below approach but it doesn't create a `devtest.txt` file. Any help please.

```
For /R %%A In (src\*.seq)Do @Echo drafting.rep:%%~nxA >> devtest.txt
```

Comment: `It doesn't work` What a precise description. What do you expect/what error message do you get? On cmd line use single percent signs for the meta variables.

Comment: It doesn't create a `devtest.txt` file. Tried both way bat and cmd.

Comment: If issued from a batch file the command will iterate from the current folder and also write/append there, you know ***what*** the current folder is when running the batch?

Comment: `For /R "C:\PathTo\src" %%A In (*.seq)Do ...`

Comment: Yes, `%ROOT%` gives the current folder/path.

Comment: Are you double-clicking the batch file to run it? The working directory probably is `C:\Windows\System32` then, so specify the (quoted) full path to `devtest.txt` then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FOR loop will find all of the files and run the ECHO command on them.

```
@SET "SEARCHDIR=C:\src"
@SET "LOGFILE=%USERPROFILE%\devtest.txt"

@IF EXIST "%LOGFILE%" (@DEL "%LOGFILE%")

@FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "%SEARCHDIR%\*.seq"') DO (
    @Echo drafting.rep:%%~nxA >>"%LOGFILE%"
)
```

Comment: With this it solved, thanks, `@SET "SEARCHDIR=%ROOT%\src"
@SET "LOGFILE=%ROOT%\devtest.txt"`

Comment: How to skip seeing output on cmd? I see `()` on each line in cmd.

Comment: @Experimenter - Glad to hear that it works for you. Each question has its own directories and file names. That is why I made variables at the top. I do not know what you mean by "I see () on each line in cmd." You could try using `@ECHO OFF` at the beginning of the .bat file script.

Comment: `@ECHO OFF` helped to skip unwanted text from cmd.